Is it acceptable to consider the use of the progressive form in R-usage as one of the polite expressions？
I have a question about the progressive form in modal and periphrastic  modal verbs.
Modal verbs: can (could), may (might), must, should
Periphrastic modal verbs: have to, ought to
Regarding the progressive form in prototypical modal verbs, it is generally used for the following purposes (Epistemic meaning: E).
(1)
a. They can't be leaving yet.
b. Marco isn't in his office. He might be working at home today.
c. John must be traveling now.
d. The fire-brigade should be arriving very soon.
On the other hand, the following usage (Root meaning: R) is also often seen.
(2)
a. I must be going soon.
c. 'I should be saying sorry,' said Charlotte.
And with the periphrastic modals:
b. Yes, we really have to be going.
d. I ought to be saying good night.
From this, it can be said that the E-usage, which is commonly used without restriction, is unmarked, and the R-usage is marked in modal + progressive form.
Now, my question is, given that in  (2a), using the progressive form in 'I must be going soon' is considered to have a polite tone compared to 'I must go soon.'
can the same be said for the following sentences (3)?
(3)
a. You may now leave for lunch, but hurry back.
b. You may now be leaving for lunch, but hurry back.
c. Borrowers may not take out of the library more than two books at a time.
d. Borrowers may not be taking out of the library more than two books at a time.
Is it acceptable to consider the use of the progressive form in R-usage as one of the polite expressions? Also, I would like to know if native speakers actually use this kind of expression.

3b and d sound concessive or possible, certainly not giving permission.

All the verbs you cite as being auxiliaries are modals. Note also that in "have to" and "ought to", the verbs are just "have" and "ought": the "to" marker belongs in the infinitival complement clause. "I have [to go]" (not "I have to [go]"

No. "You may now be leaving" would not be seen as a polite way of giving permission - and it sounds decidedly odd in combination with the instruction to "hurry back".

I've corrected the classifications (prototypical modals and periphrastic modals, using a more traditional analysis). // As Stuart says,  only a concessive reading is possible here.  This makes 3b highly improbable; 3d works say in 'Borrowers may not be taking out of the library more than two books at a time at the moment, but we need to keep the four-book limit in case this changes dramatically.'

3d just sounds weird to me, like a foreigner who doesn't know proper English conjugation (Russians often insert extra "be" auxiliaries).

@EdwinAshworth Your corrections perpetuate the myth that "have to" and "ought to" are verbs, whereas in fact it's only "have" and "ought" that are verbs. The "to" is just a marker for the VP of the subsequent clausal complement. Thus "I have [to go]" (not "I have to [go]". (Btw, the term 'periphrastic' is inappropriate, since it further perpetuates the myth.)

@BillJ Ah yes; CGELese.

@EdwinAshworth No, mainly intuition really. But if you think about it, the "to" can only be part of the complement clause. It makes no sense to say it's part of the "have" or "ought" clause.

Those seeing 'ought to' as equivalent to 'should' are more in line with Crystal's view that lexemes are not restricted to single orthographic words. Analogously, 'écouter' can't be translated solely as 'listen'.

@EdwinAshworth You're missing the point: the "to" cannot possibly be part of the modal verb. One or two catenative verbs are two-word verbal idioms, such as "would rather", but there is no question of “rather” being a verb: it is an adverb, as all dictionaries say. Whatever, the simple truth is that the "to" is a special marker for the VPs of infinitival clauses.

According to Crystal, 'kick the bucket' when used metaphorically is best regarded as a single lexeme. Its verbo-nominal internal structure is secondary. Not all see syntax as always trumping semantics. 'Galore' for instance is seen by some as both determin... and adjective simultaneously ... a view offending those who downplay semantics.

@StuartF Thank you for you comment! When is the progressive from used in English (in terms of R usage)? example, may: permission, must: obligation, should: obligation

@KateBunting  Thank you for you comment! When is the progressive form used in English (in terms of R usage)? example, may: permission, must: obligation, should: obligation

@EdwinAshworth Thank you for you comment! When is the progressive form used in English (in terms of R usage)? example, may: permission, must: obligation, should: obligation

@Barmar Thank you for you comment! When is the progressive form used in English (in terms of R usage)? example, may: permission, must: obligation, should: obligation

Answered in comments for these particular cases.

The progressive is used to soften terms of obligation ("I must be going now") but not with terms of permission. After all, telling someone they can do something is polite as it is!

@EdwinAshworth I've just spotted you last comment about Crystal (you didn't ping me). Firstly, H&P trump Crystal. Secondly, despite its idiomatic meaning, "kick the bucket" is not a single lexeme: it’s a VP with a verb as head and an NP as object complement, thus the lexical and syntactic units do match up. No one is "downplaying the semantics" as you put it, but the fact is that it is grammatically analysable.
